# What is the difference between create a static library and just import the code?

Tags: c, microcontroller, lpc

I'd like to know what is the difference and also what is better, create a static library with the common code I need or just import files to the project.

Comment: What do you mean by "import"?

Comment: Why a static library? Why not a dynamic library?

Comment: When using a static library, things are compiled already -> shorter build time. When using sources that are build together with your main project you can be sure that any changes in the build environment (new compiler etc) dont cause issues.

Comment: with import I mean put the source code of the library within the project to be compiled with it.

Comment: I believe that to have dynamic libraries I must have a OS and in this case I haven't. I'm programming for microcontrolled system.

Answer (score 1):

With a library, you can distribute the code w/o the source.  If you have the source, then your compiler has the opportunity to optimize that code.

"Better" depends on what your criteria are.

Comment: "If you have the source, then your compiler has the opportunity to optimize that code." - it also has the possibility of optimization without the source.

Answer (score 1):

One other difference in embedded projects is that you may want to compile the library with different project settings, so that would be one advantage.  However, the optimizer may be able to do more with using registers to pass variables, etc if all the source is in the project.

Embedded compilers can be **very** terrible, and its the case that sometimes you have to hand feed them.  (I remember one 8051 c compiler that wouldn't even do constant expression folding, uggh.)

Answer (score 0):

You mean manually move the code over? I think the difference is during linking, compiler optimization is slightly different. Static library is essentially "copy over the exposed code" which happens during compile time.

It is more a form of code reuse to me. Dynamic library on the other hand, is more complicated and flexible as the functions are called at runtime only. As a result, programs linked with dynamic library has less information in binary comparing to those compiled with static library using exact same source. I did comparison myself a while ago.

And yes, Scott is absolutely right regarding code distribution.

Comment: ".. the difference is during linking, compiler optimization is slightly different." - at link-time, the compiler has done its job already and it is up to the linker to optimize (e.g. remove unused code).

Comment: @Till If I do remember my compiler course correctly, there is optimization during link stage as well. My phrasing is incorrect though, it should be `linker optimization`.